Can I manipulate props and then pass to child component in HOC
I am trying to create this HOC-->
export const hocGrid = (Grid) => {

    return ({ data, config, id = uuidv4(), adaptableReady, autosizeAllColumns, removeLoader }) => {
        return (
            <Grid data={data} config={config} id={id} adaptableReady={adaptableReady} autosizeAllColumns={autosizeAllColumns} removeLoader={removeLoader} />
        )
    }
}

this Grid component receives data and config as props, data is array of object and config is object
I want to modify these data and config and then pass to Grid. Is this possible through HOC?

So you want your HOC to modify grid and data? You can modify it before you pass them and return your Grid in the inner most function.

How do you want to modify them? Did you try and what's the issue?

You can modify data and config in the body of the inner function
export const hocGrid = (Grid) => {
  return ({ data, config, id, adaptableReady, autosizeAllColumns, removeLoader }) => {
    const newData = data.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      // add new items here if needed
    }));

    const newConfig = {
      ...config,
      // add new property and value here if needed
    };

    return (
      <Grid
        data={newData}
        config={newConfig}
        id={id}
        adaptableReady={adaptableReady}
        autosizeAllColumns={autosizeAllColumns}
        removeLoader={removeLoader}
      />
    );
  };
}

